# My 5Ghz network is not visible, asus router

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I have an asus router with dualband. Tried to connect to 5Ghz band with my laptop, lenovo z50 but there was no 5Ghz band available.

So I bought a USB dongle with 802.11ac, and I can see lists of 5Ghz wifis of my neighbors, but still cannot see my own 5Ghz wifi router. Only 2.4Ghz.

I am connecting to the 5Ghz band with my phone I know it's working, the 5Ghz is not hidden network. It is broadcasting SSID. I've also tried to add manually so It connects to my specific SSID and AES key. But still not working.

My usb wifi has 2.4Ghz, 2.4+5Ghz and 5Ghz channel modes. 
My onboard laptop wifi Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n has bandwidth value 20_40Mhz and 20Mhz only modes. Currently on 20_40Mhz mode. Wireless mode Auto with IEEE 802.11b and IEEE 802.11b/g. Currently on 802.11b.

Router is Asus RT-AC68U.

Answer (score 12):

Did you try this one:  Go into the WiFi router settings and try manually setting the 5 GHz network to a channel between 36-48 or 149-165. The in-between channels (50-144) are DFS - dynamic frequency select. Not all devices support them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)

What happened is after the 5 GHz band was made open, researchers discovered that some of the frequencies right in the middle of it were very useful for a new form of doppler weather radar, which is now used at many airports. So the FCC went back and revised the standard. The 5 GHz frequencies are still open, but the channels which can interfere with weather radar are classified as DFS. WiFi equipment can use those channels, but if they detect weather radar being used, the equipment has to automatically switch to a different channel.

Some WiFi equipment does this. The vast majority simply block the DFS channels from being used at all (that way they don't have to waste time trying to detect weather radar). If you've got a router which supports DFS set to auto, it can end up on one of the DFS channels. But if your PC's WiFi adapter simply blocks DFS channels, you won't be able to see the router when it's on a DFS channel. The fix is to manually assign your router's 5 GHz WiFi to a non-DFS channel. (Take care to select a channel with 40 or 80 MHz bandwidth on the linked chart if you want to maximize bandwidth.)

Comment: Well, changing the channel from Automatic (although it was set on 36 apparently) to 40 did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: I confirm that my ASUS GT-AX series router, residing in EU, with the "Auto select channel including DFS channels" option unchecked, the 5GHz network becomes visible again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved by setting Region to Europe (was China as a 'grey' import router) under Wireless, Professional settings. Seems to influence choice of channel as already mentioned. Can also de-select 'Auto select channel including DFS channels' if needed (mine worked w/o this) under Wireless, General.

Answer (score 2):

I have a BRT-AC828 with FW 3.0.0.4.382_70348 and all of a sudden lost the 5GHz wireless function, 2,4GHz was still working without any issues.
Tried a reboot, tried disabling 5GHZ and enabling it again and tried several other options out there, but without any luck.

Until I enabled TELNET, then all of a sudden the 5 GHZ SSID appeared again. But when I disable TELNET is goes away.
I also changed the control channel (Wireless \ General) from AUTO(100) to manual 36.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced high ping (hundreds of ms) and failing network connectivity on my macbook when my router switched to channel 100 on 5GHz. By disabling "Auto select channel including DFS channels" I solved the issue.

There are 16 DFS channels: 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, and 144. ([DFS channels](https://www.aami.org/medical-device-connectivity/medical-device-connectivity-faqs-standards-802-11))

When I noticed the network is slow again I checked which channel is being used at the moment and it was channel 100 in ma case. I tried to manually select "non-DFS" channel and the ping was totally fine again!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).